# R lines() command shows crossed lines

Tags: r, plot, line

When I add `lines()` to `hist()` I get unexplainable crossed lines, could you tell me why? Please[image: Problem]

```
x <- 
  rgamma(100, shape = 1, rate = 2)

gamma_distr <-
  fitdistr(x, densfun="gamma")

pdf_gamma <- 
  dgamma(x,
         shape = gamma_distr$estimate[1],
         rate = gamma_distr$estimate[2])

hist(x, 100, freq = FALSE)
lines(x = x, y = pdf_gamma, col="red")
```

Comment: because `lines` plots in the order that the values are given: `lines(x[order(x)], pdf_gamma[order(x)], col="red")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```r
library(MASS)

x <- rgamma(100, shape = 1, rate = 2)

gamma_distr <- fitdistr(x, densfun="gamma")

hist(x, 100, freq = FALSE)
curve(dgamma(x,
             shape = gamma_distr$estimate[1],
             rate = gamma_distr$estimate[2]), col="red", add = T)
```